# How does `NestJS` knows how to serialize a value of an object given the annotated return type on the handler?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

How does `NestJS` knows how to serialize a value of an object given the annotated return type on the handler?

Example:

```
type User = {
  id: number,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  age: number,
  occupation: string,
  role: Role,
}

enum Role {
  USER,
  ADMIN,
  OWNER,
}

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Jon",
    lastName: "Henry",
    age:52,
    occupation: "SWE",
    role: Role.USER,
  }
]

function getUserOnlyFirstName(id: number): Pick<User, "firstName"> | undefined {
  for (const user of users) {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return user;
    }
  }
  return;
}
const user = getUserOnlyFirstName(1);

console.log(user)
```

In `NestJS`, the code snippet above with the appropriate imports, e.g. importing Get from @nestjs/common etc, will result in the returned response, e.g. {"firstName": "Jon"}, despite the entire `user` variable is of type `User`.

How does `NestJS` accomplish this? I am asking because types are erased at runtime and it seems impossible to use types as values or even the property keys of types in compile time codes, i.e. massage the value of some type such that it only contains properties of another type.

Comment: Can you reduce the example to necessary parts only (e.g. the Role enum is not needed). Also, there is no NestJS code in the example. Please add the @Get annotation and such where you intend it.

Comment: Nest shouldn't know anything about that by default. It might be related to your returned DTO class, i.e. returning an instance of `User` that has specific `@Expose()` annotations and using the `ClassSerializationInterceptor` but without an example I wouldn't be able to say. The `Pick<User, 'firstName'>` wouldn't be enough on its own for Nest to do anything

Comment: Typescript playground doesn't allow me to import NestJS to give a thorough example. I will try other playgrounds to see if that is possible.